# How does the Friedman test extend the sign test?

Tags: nonparametric, friedman-test, sign-test

Every book/article claims this as if it's self-evident, but I have a hard time figuring out why. How do you get from the sum-of-squares style statistic of Friedman to the difference statistic involved in the sign test?

Comment: Perhaps a proper reference is due. In any case, what does the sign test do? What does it test? Does it only involve one sample and if so, what should the extension do for $k$ samples? Does Friedman do the job?